# angularjs directive - getting parentScope undefined error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

we have nested directive in application.
We are passing controller's scope.openFundReport to inner directive.

```
<div ng-controller="app"> 
  <sa-grid src="accounts"> 
      <my-directive data="row.funds" onclick="parentScope.openFundReport(f)"  />
   </sa-grid>
```

directive js

```
    angular.module("app").directive("myDirective",function(){
     return{
            restrict:"E",
               scope:{
                      data:"=", 
                      onclick="&"
                     },
              controller : function($scope){
                    $scope.openReport=function(f){
                    $scope.onclick({f:f});
                    }
                 },
               templateUrl="t.html"
             }
         }

        });
```

---

directive html

```
  <div> 
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="f in funds">
         <a ng-click="openReport(f)">{{f.symbol}}</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

---

On clicking of link, controller's openFundReport function get called properly. 
but Error is getting logged in browser, 
**Uncaught ReferenceError: parentScope is not defined (index):1
onclick**

JS Fiddler example http://jsfiddle.net/9X3V4/2/

Comment: your code is full of errors(missing brackets...) set up a working fiddle or plnkr to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: And where is `parentScope` declared?

Comment: @Chandermani parentScope defined inside sa-grid directive. sa-grid is not my part. they are setting parentScope to $scope.$parent. to pass my controller's method to inner grid, i have to pass it as parentScope.method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be obvious, but it took *way* too long for me to see it.  You're passing `openFR` through the `onclick` attribute, which works.  But `onclick` is also a standard javascript event.  After Angular does its thing, javascript handles the event, and of course it can't find `openFR`.  The solution is to just name your attribute something else, like 'click', or 'clickEvent'.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/pNrUT/)

Answer (score -1):

if you wish to execute a function onclick you need to use = instead of  & then invoke that function on a designated event fired by your directive,  something like

```
 angular.module("app").directive("myDirective",function(){
 return{
        restrict:"E",
           scope:{
                  data:"=", 
                  onclick="="
                 },
          controller : function($scope){
                $scope.openReport=function(f){}
            },
           templateUrl="t.html"
         }
     }

    });
```

i have never attempted this, but it should work by using = you are binding to the parents scope function. if this doesn't do the trick you might want to create an ngClick handler in the directive and then call the passed function from within the handler

NOTE: this is my own tested directive

```
   directive('dir3', [ function() {
       return {
        restrict:'C',
        template:'<button ng-click="click()"></button>',
        scope:{
            click:'='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       }
     }}]);
```

it usage

```
  <div click="click" class="dir3">click</div>
```

the controller portion

```
     $scope.click=function(){
          alert('hola');
      }
```

Comment: `onClick=&` is the correct way. = is used for 2 way binding.

Comment: & turns anything in text, = keeps references thats why i thought it would be better to use = instead of &

Comment: am actively requesting that when ever someone down votes provide an explanation to either refute or correct, down voting just because is nor polite and even less educative.

Comment: I didnt downvote you but even with using & , it should work as expected(I tried , I was surprised about it too ). http://plnkr.co/edit/17jfkvfN0ksUzjdi6URZ?p=preview

Comment: wasn't aware of that sintax, but to be honest not because i wrote it, but i kind a lik imne better i feel it more clean and since it actually works, could you please up vote my response.. at least 2 pts so i can get my rightfull rate back?

Comment: The `&` binding is the preferred way to bind to a function.  The `=` binding is for two-way binding to a model.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: read up, already explained why of the solution, using = might be "wrong" most of the times, but in this case it works, and from my point of view is more elegant and readable

Comment: Are you confusing `@` and `&`?  Not sure how `=` is more elegant, and just because it happens to work doesn't mean it's the right way.  In any case, it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: i was confusing @ with & now that you mention it, but  it did had to do with the problem since allows the directive to wire the function directly.

Comment: His directive was already wired correctly using `&` (the controller function *was* being called).  The problem was the mysterious error message that was also occurring (not hurting anything, just annoying).

Comment: i revisited the docs quite a change, ill go through it again sicen some core stuff since to be changed. and yes i see that & is good for wiring callbacks. thank you.